# How do I convert an ISO 8601 string to time_t in C++?

Tags: c++, time, iso, time-t

Does anyone know how to go from an [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-formatted date/time string to a `time_t`?
I am using C++ and it needs to work on Windows and Mac.

I have written the code but I am sure there is a version that is more "standard."

I will get a date like `2011-03-21 20:25` and I have to tell if the time is in the past or the future.

Comment: There's a similar discussion about a cross-platform `strptime` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows).  You may want ravenspoint's answer, and use boost:  `#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"`

Answer (score 8):

One ugly hack I thought would be fun: since you only want to determine which date/time is bigger, you can convert the date to string and compare strings. ;-) (The upside is you do not need strptime which is not available everywhere.)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *str = "2011-03-21 20:25";
    char nowbuf[100];
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *nowtm;
    nowtm = localtime(&now);
    strftime(nowbuf, sizeof(nowbuf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", nowtm);
    if (strncmp(str, nowbuf, strlen(str)) >= 0) puts("future"); else puts("past");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While I instinctively cringe at such an idea... that is the point of the "YYYYMMDD HHMMSS" format - ascii comparisons actually work.  The risk, of course is if he starts getting dates in a different format in the future.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`strptime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) to convert from a string to a `struct tm`, and then you can use [`mktime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) to convert from a `struct tm` to a `time_t`.  For example:

```
// Error checking omitted for expository purposes
const char *timestr = "2011-03-21 20:25";
struct tm t;
strptime(timestr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", &t);
time_t t2 = mktime(&t);
// Now compare t2 with time(NULL) etc.
```

Comment: strptime isn't standard c. Will it be available on Windows?

Comment: @Null Set: Oops you're right, forgot about that.  `strptime` is only defined by POSIX.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667250/strptime-in-windows .

Answer (score 1):

If the timestamp is in the local timezone the following method converts from ISO8601 to UTC. Also it is not ignoring potential daylight saving. It is standard C99.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t from_iso8601_utc(const char* dateStr)
{
    struct tm t;
    int success = sscanf(dateStr, "%d-%d-%dT%d:%dZ", /* */
                         &t.tm_year, &t.tm_mon, &t.tm_mday, &t.tm_hour, &t.tm_min);
    if (success != 5) {
        return 0;
    }

    /* compensate expected ranges */
    t.tm_year = t.tm_year - 1900;
    t.tm_mon = t.tm_mon - 1;
    t.tm_sec = 0;
    t.tm_wday = 0;
    t.tm_yday = 0;
    t.tm_isdst = 0;

    time_t localTime = mktime(&t);
    time_t utcTime = localTime - timezone;
    return utcTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from @Peter Kofler answer for `2022-12-13T17:15:53.499Z` kind of dates:

```
int64_t dateTime_parse(char *dateString)
{
  char *format = "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d.%dZ";
  
  struct tm t{};
  int msec;
  int parseCount = sscanf(dateString, format, &t.tm_year, &t.tm_mon, 
                          &t.tm_mday, &t.tm_hour, &t.tm_min, &t.tm_sec, &msec);
  if (parseCount < 7)
  {
    return - 1;
  }
  t.tm_year -= 1900;
  t.tm_mon -= 1;
  t.tm_isdst = -1;               //let mktime figure out DST

  int64_t result = mktime(&t);   //this is time_t type
  result *= 1000;
  result += msec;

  return result;
}
```

Note that `mktime` assumes first parameter to be a pointer to *local* time. If you want the date string to be parsed as UTC, use *_mkgmtime* instead (in windows).