# Strptime open source code not implementing

Tags: c, string, time

I am trying to convert a string into time format. As I read here on stackoverflow, the discussion of converting a string into time format. The function `strptime()` has been used for the same. I am also using the `strptime()` in my program in C, in windows. I tried to copy the open source strptime code from the following link in my program, but there are too many headerfiles missing. I created those headerfiles too, but still the code is not working and giving many warnings.

Please help.

http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/time/strptime.c?rev=HEAD

Thanks much.

Comment: Did you `#include <time.h>`?

Comment: Windows doesn't have `strptime(3)`. You need to implement it yourself, or use someone else's implementation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667250/strptime-in-windows

Comment: @Filipe: thanks much. Is there any other function in C with windows to convert string to time format without implementing this written strptime function?

Comment: @learningpal I'm afraid there isn't.

Comment: See the answer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

From the (Linux) manual page for [`strptime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime):

> Conforming To
>
> SUSv2, POSIX.1-2001.

Those are Unix specifications; Windows doesn't implement them in general.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an open source implementation of strptime. You can use that if the license fits your legal status.

Shamelessly stolen from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/25a654f9-b6b6-490a-8f36-c87483bb36b7/strptime-on-windows).

```
/*  $NetBSD: strptime.c,v 1.28 2008/04/28 20:23:01 martin Exp $ */ 

/*-
 * Copyright (c) 1997, 1998, 2005, 2008 The NetBSD Foundation, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This code was contributed to The NetBSD Foundation by Klaus Klein.
 * Heavily optimised by David Laight
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE NETBSD FOUNDATION, INC. AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
 * TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE FOUNDATION OR CONTRIBUTORS
 * BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 
#include <sys/cdefs.h> 
#if defined(LIBC_SCCS) && !defined(lint) 
__RCSID("$NetBSD: strptime.c,v 1.28 2008/04/28 20:23:01 martin Exp $"); 
#endif 
#include "namespace.h" 
#include <sys/localedef.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <locale.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <tzfile.h> 
#ifdef __weak_alias 
__weak_alias(strptime,_strptime) 
#endif 
#define _ctloc(x)       (_CurrentTimeLocale->x) 

/*
 * We do not implement alternate representations. However, we always
 * check whether a given modifier is allowed for a certain conversion.
 */ 
#define ALT_E           0x01 
#define ALT_O           0x02 
#define LEGAL_ALT(x)        { if (alt_format & ~(x)) return NULL; } 

static const char gmt[4] = { "GMT" }; 

static const u_char *conv_num(const unsigned char *, int *, uint, uint); 
static const u_char *find_string(const u_char *, int *, const char * const *, 
    const char * const *, int); 


char * 
strptime(const char *buf, const char *fmt, struct tm *tm) 
{ 
    unsigned char c; 
    const unsigned char *bp; 
    int alt_format, i, split_year = 0; 
    const char *new_fmt; 

    bp = (const u_char *)buf; 

    while (bp != NULL && (c = *fmt++) != '\0') { 
        /* Clear `alternate' modifier prior to new conversion. */ 
        alt_format = 0; 
        i = 0; 

        /* Eat up white-space. */ 
        if (isspace(c)) { 
            while (isspace(*bp)) 
                bp++; 
            continue; 
        } 

        if (c != '%') 
            goto literal; 


again:      switch (c = *fmt++) { 
        case '%':   /* "%%" is converted to "%". */ 
literal: 
            if (c != *bp++) 
                return NULL; 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            continue; 

        /*
         * "Alternative" modifiers. Just set the appropriate flag
         * and start over again.
         */ 
        case 'E':   /* "%E?" alternative conversion modifier. */ 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            alt_format |= ALT_E; 
            goto again; 

        case 'O':   /* "%O?" alternative conversion modifier. */ 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            alt_format |= ALT_O; 
            goto again; 

        /*
         * "Complex" conversion rules, implemented through recursion.
         */ 
        case 'c':   /* Date and time, using the locale's format. */ 
            new_fmt = _ctloc(d_t_fmt); 
            goto recurse; 

        case 'D':   /* The date as "%m/%d/%y". */ 
            new_fmt = "%m/%d/%y"; 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            goto recurse; 

        case 'F':   /* The date as "%Y-%m-%d". */ 
            new_fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"; 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            goto recurse; 

        case 'R':   /* The time as "%H:%M". */ 
            new_fmt = "%H:%M"; 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            goto recurse; 

        case 'r':   /* The time in 12-hour clock representation. */ 
            new_fmt =_ctloc(t_fmt_ampm); 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            goto recurse; 

        case 'T':   /* The time as "%H:%M:%S". */ 
            new_fmt = "%H:%M:%S"; 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            goto recurse; 

        case 'X':   /* The time, using the locale's format. */ 
            new_fmt =_ctloc(t_fmt); 
            goto recurse; 

        case 'x':   /* The date, using the locale's format. */ 
            new_fmt =_ctloc(d_fmt); 
            recurse: 
            bp = (const u_char *)strptime((const char *)bp, 
                                new_fmt, tm); 
            LEGAL_ALT(ALT_E); 
            continue; 

        /*
         * "Elementary" conversion rules.
         */ 
        case 'A':   /* The day of week, using the locale's form. */ 
        case 'a': 
            bp = find_string(bp, &tm->tm_wday, _ctloc(day), 
                    _ctloc(abday), 7); 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            continue; 

        case 'B':   /* The month, using the locale's form. */ 
        case 'b': 
        case 'h': 
            bp = find_string(bp, &tm->tm_mon, _ctloc(mon), 
                    _ctloc(abmon), 12); 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            continue; 

        case 'C':   /* The century number. */ 
            i = 20; 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &i, 0, 99); 

            i = i * 100 - TM_YEAR_BASE; 
            if (split_year) 
                i += tm->tm_year % 100; 
            split_year = 1; 
            tm->tm_year = i; 
            LEGAL_ALT(ALT_E); 
            continue; 

        case 'd':   /* The day of month. */ 
        case 'e': 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &tm->tm_mday, 1, 31); 
            LEGAL_ALT(ALT_O); 
            continue; 

        case 'k':   /* The hour (24-hour clock representation). */ 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            /* FALLTHROUGH */ 
        case 'H': 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &tm->tm_hour, 0, 23); 
            LEGAL_ALT(ALT_O); 
            continue; 

        case 'l':   /* The hour (12-hour clock representation). */ 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            /* FALLTHROUGH */ 
        case 'I': 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &tm->tm_hour, 1, 12); 
            if (tm->tm_hour == 12) 
                tm->tm_hour = 0; 
            LEGAL_ALT(ALT_O); 
            continue; 

        case 'j':   /* The day of year. */ 
            i = 1; 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &i, 1, 366); 
            tm->tm_yday = i - 1; 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            continue; 

        case 'M':   /* The minute. */ 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &tm->tm_min, 0, 59); 
            LEGAL_ALT(ALT_O); 
            continue; 

        case 'm':   /* The month. */ 
            i = 1; 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &i, 1, 12); 
            tm->tm_mon = i - 1; 
            LEGAL_ALT(ALT_O); 
            continue; 

        case 'p':   /* The locale's equivalent of AM/PM. */ 
            bp = find_string(bp, &i, _ctloc(am_pm), NULL, 2); 
            if (tm->tm_hour > 11) 
                return NULL; 
            tm->tm_hour += i * 12; 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            continue; 

        case 'S':   /* The seconds. */ 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &tm->tm_sec, 0, 61); 
            LEGAL_ALT(ALT_O); 
            continue; 

        case 'U':   /* The week of year, beginning on sunday. */ 
        case 'W':   /* The week of year, beginning on monday. */ 
            /*
             * XXX This is bogus, as we can not assume any valid
             * information present in the tm structure at this
             * point to calculate a real value, so just check the
             * range for now.
             */ 
             bp = conv_num(bp, &i, 0, 53); 
             LEGAL_ALT(ALT_O); 
             continue; 

        case 'w':   /* The day of week, beginning on sunday. */ 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &tm->tm_wday, 0, 6); 
            LEGAL_ALT(ALT_O); 
            continue; 

        case 'Y':   /* The year. */ 
            i = TM_YEAR_BASE;   /* just for data sanity... */ 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &i, 0, 9999); 
            tm->tm_year = i - TM_YEAR_BASE; 
            LEGAL_ALT(ALT_E); 
            continue; 

        case 'y':   /* The year within 100 years of the epoch. */ 
            /* LEGAL_ALT(ALT_E | ALT_O); */ 
            bp = conv_num(bp, &i, 0, 99); 

            if (split_year) 
                /* preserve century */ 
                i += (tm->tm_year / 100) * 100; 
            else { 
                split_year = 1; 
                if (i <= 68) 
                    i = i + 2000 - TM_YEAR_BASE; 
                else 
                    i = i + 1900 - TM_YEAR_BASE; 
            } 
            tm->tm_year = i; 
            continue; 

        case 'Z': 
            tzset(); 
            if (strncmp((const char *)bp, gmt, 3) == 0) { 
                tm->tm_isdst = 0; 
#ifdef TM_GMTOFF 
                tm->TM_GMTOFF = 0; 
#endif 
#ifdef TM_ZONE 
                tm->TM_ZONE = gmt; 
#endif 
                bp += 3; 
            } else { 
                const unsigned char *ep; 

                ep = find_string(bp, &i, 
                             (const char * const *)tzname, 
                              NULL, 2); 
                if (ep != NULL) { 
                    tm->tm_isdst = i; 
#ifdef TM_GMTOFF 
                    tm->TM_GMTOFF = -(timezone); 
#endif 
#ifdef TM_ZONE 
                    tm->TM_ZONE = tzname[i]; 
#endif 
                } 
                bp = ep; 
            } 
            continue; 

        /*
         * Miscellaneous conversions.
         */ 
        case 'n':   /* Any kind of white-space. */ 
        case 't': 
            while (isspace(*bp)) 
                bp++; 
            LEGAL_ALT(0); 
            continue; 


        default:    /* Unknown/unsupported conversion. */ 
            return NULL; 
        } 
    } 

    return __UNCONST(bp); 
} 


static const u_char * 
conv_num(const unsigned char *buf, int *dest, uint llim, uint ulim) 
{ 
    uint result = 0; 
    unsigned char ch; 

    /* The limit also determines the number of valid digits. */ 
    uint rulim = ulim; 

    ch = *buf; 
    if (ch < '0' || ch > '9') 
        return NULL; 

    do { 
        result *= 10; 
        result += ch - '0'; 
        rulim /= 10; 
        ch = *++buf; 
    } while ((result * 10 <= ulim) && rulim && ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'); 

    if (result < llim || result > ulim) 
        return NULL; 

    *dest = result; 
    return buf; 
} 

static const u_char * 
find_string(const u_char *bp, int *tgt, const char * const *n1, 
        const char * const *n2, int c) 
{ 
    int i; 
    unsigned int len; 

    /* check full name - then abbreviated ones */ 
    for (; n1 != NULL; n1 = n2, n2 = NULL) { 
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++, n1++) { 
            len = strlen(*n1); 
            if (strncasecmp(*n1, (const char *)bp, len) == 0) { 
                *tgt = i; 
                return bp + len; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /* Nothing matched */ 
    return NULL; 
}
```

Comment: @ Ishay: Thanks much for answer. I copied this above code in another c file named strptime.c and compiled it with my main file. Before that I copied the open source codes for sys/cdefs.h, namespace.h,  sys/localedef.h, and tzfile.h and included in my main program. But I am getting many errors and warnings in the code.